# How do I change material render preview?

Tags: interface, shaders, customization

[image]

I want to change the render material preview by removing the floor in the preview and replacing all the lighting and environment in it with an hdri image, and setting an image as a background, so that the render preview changes from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I also want the material shown in the preview to look the same in Blender's file browser when I use `append`, like this:

[image: der]

So how do I do all this?
I do not mind using programming with Python if there is no other than this solution.

Comment: I think you would have to [compile blender by yourself](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender). According to: https://developer.blender.org/T57683 it's just a blend file, located here: `release/datafiles/`...

Comment: This seems especially difficult for a beginner like me. Can't I use Python inside Blender to create a panel that contains two layers of images (background image - static topped by an image layer of the material with a transparent background) as a material preview?

Answer (score -1):

Had the same question found your then just worked it out by pick things.

Top right hand corner of the 3D viewport there is a drop down arrow.
In viewport shading you can select scene lights and scene world.
I didn't try to see if this would give you the result your looking for but it has worked for me.

Regards